# How can I customize the prompt on a list search box

Tags: 2013, custom-form, list-search-box

For several reasons, I need to customize the prompt shown in the list search box, i.e. the one that says "Find an item".

Is there an official way to do this, via a display template or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Unforthenatlly, **No** there's not a display tmplate realted to `List search box` at Display Template folder within `http://Sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/`,

But You can do this for `Site Search Box`, where at `Sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/` , there are  display templates for the following search box

- Default Search Box. (Control_SearchBox)
- Site Search Box. (Control_SearchBox_Compact)

And You can create element.xml via visual studio to change for example the `Search This Site` Promoted text at `InitialPrompt` property

```
<Property Name="InitialPrompt">Search SharePoint site</Property>
```

Here the full example to do this [Replacing the OOTB Small Search Input Box in SharePoint 2013](https://www.eliostruyf.com/replacing-the-ootb-small-search-input-box-for-sharepoint-2013/)

So for `List Search Box` I customize it via Javascript as the following :

```
<script>
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changefinditem");
    function changefinditem() {
      document.getElementById("inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput").value = "Find Qassas";
    }

</script>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something very similar to the suggestion of M.Qassas above.
The code looks like this:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("CustomizeListSearchBox");

function CustomizeListSearchBox()
{
    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsparent') {
            e.target.children[0].addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(xe) {
                e.target.children[0].value = 'Search just this list';
            }, false);
        }
    });
}
```

For reasons I don't understand, not only does the List Search Box get inserted into the DOM at a relatively late stage, but the prompt itself is set at an even later stage.

Consequently, what I had to do was listen for a DOMNodeInserted event, check to see it was the parent of the list search box, and then attach a listener to the list search box itself and listen for DOMAttrModified in order to be sure I could set the prompt without it being overwritten.

The code can obviously be improved, when I understand the sequence of events better.

Josh

Comment: Dear @josh Great Job , Meanwhile you said I used the similar suggestion fro me  But I am wondering Is my answer and workaround code not helped and working for you ? I also shared print screen from output in my environment that worked correctly ? !! and also I  added more clarification  about why you can't do this in display template ?! this was your question , you need to know it's possible or not ?!! I have answered this and introduced also a workaround so should you tell me why this answer is not useful for you ?  thanks for your response :)

Comment: To tell you the truth, I didn't see your workaround until I'd got something to work. But thanks anyway, and for the enlightenment of no display template (which I think Microsoft should remedy).

Comment: thanks , I was only need to know if my answer is not correct for you or not , so please if my answer is considered an aswer to your question , should you set as answer to be useful for all , thanks for appriciating my time :)

Answer (score 0):

edit the Display Templates - *Control_SearchBox.html* file and set your text

```
if($isNull(prompt)){
    prompt = "Find an item";
}
```

see details in 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-change-the-text-that-is-displayed-in-the-search-box-web-part